# Array to CSV shifted rows

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am trying to convert the below array to a downloadable csv with three columns and three rows. For some reason, the below functions create four columns instead of three with some of the rows shifted over.

I was wondering if someone can help me identify why this is?

Many thanks in advance!

```
$ary = array(
                array("1", "Bob", "Saget"),
                array("2", "Luke", "Skywalker"),
                array("3", "Owen", "Wilson")
            );

$csv = arrayToCsv($ary);
downloadCSV($csv);


function arrayToCsv($array) {
    $csv = array();
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            $csv[] = arrayToCsv($item) . "\n";
        } else {
            $csv[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return implode(',', $csv);
} 


function downloadCSV($csv){
    $fileName = 'customer-list.csv';

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

    echo $csv;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using `fputcsv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your outer call to `arrayToCsv()` calls itself for each element of the array. The inner call puts commas between each element of the sub-array, and then adds a newline to the end. The outer call collects these in a new array, and then separates them with commas. This puts an extra comma at the beginning of each line except the first.

You need to process the outer array differently from the sub-arrays. Implode with `,` when processing the sub-arrays, implode with `\n` when processing the outer array.

```
function arrayToCsv($array) {
    return implode("\n", array_map(function($subarray) {
        return implode(",", $subarray);
    }, $array));
}
```

Or you could just use `fputcsv`:

```
$fp = fopen("php://stdout", "w");
foreach ($ary as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you! works well. I went with your first suggestion as file IO is disabled on the server I'm working on.